# Melhorando o retorno de um resultado específico

Tags: django, django-queryset, django-templates

Acho que estou desaprendendo o básico!

Eu tenho um resultado que me retorna apenas um elemento no dicionário:

```
[{'quant': 236, 'district': 'Centro'}]
```

Meu contexto é:

```
context['Districts'] = d
```

Como eu faço para no template eu escrever algo como

```
{{ Districts.district }} - {{ Districts.quant }}
```

ao invés de

```
{% for i in vehicleDistrict %}
    {{ i.dealership__district }} - {{ i.quant }}
{% endfor %}
```

Já que a interação é de apenas um item?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Na realidade ele retorna apenas um elemento na lista, para isso basta pegar o primeiro elemento (único neste caso) e passar para o template.

view:

```
d = [{'quant': 236, 'district': 'Centro'}][0]
```

template:

```
{{ d.quant }} - {{ d.district }}
```

Você ainda pode usar diretamente no template este recurso mas eu não acho uma boa prática:

```
{{ District.0.quant }}
```